# Call function from Href or RouterLink in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular library project.
I had a button in library on whose click I fire an output event .
My Library consumer recives this output and redirects user to another page.

There is a change which wants us to have a right click on button and Open in new Tab feature.
I have changed button to an  tag and I am now handling the output event via (click) in   tag
I want to call showDetails() function on href of  tag too.

Html of my library which is not working:

```
 <a href="{{javascript: showDetails()}}"  (click)="showDetails()">
```

.ts code of library

```
@Output() showDetailRequested = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    showDetails() {
        this.showDetailRequested.emit();
      }
```

Library consumer Html code

```
 <lib-comp (showDetailRequested)="onShowDetailRequested()"></lib-comp>
```

Library ts code

```
onShowDetailRequested() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`balh/${this.blah.blahId}`);
  }
```

}

I really can't do anything like this

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/somepath']" (click)="showDetails()">Home</a>
```

as this some path is unknown and we get to know this path when user of my library recieves the output fired from showDetails method.

I tried below one and it is not working too

```
<a routerLink="{{showDetails()}}"   (click)="showDetails()">
```

Can I get some help in this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-before-routing-jdufpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Notice in your code, you have specified it like this, which the `routerLink` is just plain `routerLink` without any brackets in it `[routerLink]` even though you are invoking a function, thus, when you check you addressbar, your url is somehow like this: `/log%28'second'%29` since it though that the `log('second')` is a string and nothing should be invoked with

```
<a routerLink="log('second')" (click)="log('second');">Second</a>
```

If you have it this way with brackets `[]` you must ensure that your `log` function returns the path for the routerLink to redirect to

```
<a [routerLink]="log('second')" (click)="log('second');">Second</a>
```

In your component, you can have it like this:

```
log(text: string) {
  ...

  return text;         // or any path, you want to return
}
```

But again as specified below, it is quite expensive to call a function twice for a single element. You can choose the alternatives below

---

**Example #1**

If you want to perform some logic before redirecting to a specific route, you can implement it like this instead:

*Component*

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  log(text: string) {
    console.log(text);
    this.clickVal = text;

    this.router.navigate([text]);          // Add Router Navigate on this line and your 'text' parameter as it's route to redirect to
  }
}
```

*Template*

```
....

<a (click)="log('second');">Second</a>        // Just (click), avoid putting [routerLink] and (click) as you can perform the redirection inside your click function
```

**NOTE:**

- If you'll put `href` inside your anchor tag, it will hard reload the page so your `clickVal` will not be printed anymore. Instead, style your anchor tags uniformly, anchor tags that don't have any `href` on them

---

**Example #2**

*Component*

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

  log(text: string) {             // same as your original code
    console.log(text);
    this.clickVal = text;
  }
}
```

*Template*

```
....
// Specify the path of your routerLink without invoking similar function as your
// click, as you don't want to invoke the function twice for just 1 element.

<a routerLink="second" (click)="log('second');">Second</a>
```

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Pass `balh/${this.blah.blahId}` as `@Input()` to `lib-comp` instead of emitting the mouse event.